# What package is vm() from in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to run someone else's code, but cannot find what package contains the function `vm()`. It is used below with `ID` which is a column in `data` and `GRM` which is a genomic relationship matrix.

```
model10.asr <- asreml(fixed = SPIG_NOSE ~    TypeOfBirthMod:TypeOfRearing+ ContempGrp + Sex_Corrected + Het,
                      random = ~ vm(ID, GRM),
                      na.action = na.method(x = "include", y = "include"), 
                      keep.order = TRUE,
                      dense = list(SheepGeneticsID = GRM),
                      data = data,
                      workspace=512e06)
```

I have tried searching to packages, and only found `nomcluster` which didn't work.

Comment: Do you have an AS-REML license?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a function *per se*, it's part of the syntax of the `ASREML-R` package, which is commercial (not open-source). You can find more information about it here: https://asreml.kb.vsni.co.uk/ . I have no idea if they have cheap student or academic licenses.

Some of their documentation is online, although I don't know if it will completely answer your question (e.g. search https://asreml.kb.vsni.co.uk/knowledge-base/asreml/ for "vm").

Comment: ... if the package is installed and loaded ... (`help.search("vm", agrep = FALSE)` will work if the package is installed but not loaded ... `library(sos); findFn("vm")` **may** find it if it's not installed but on CRAN ...)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right @BenBolker. It looks like an argument of `asreml`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The vm package is from thestatsmodelslibrary in R.

Comment: this doesn't seem particularly useful.  Even if there is a `vm()` function in some other R package, how did you find it? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).